# Logging in Selenium Webdriver using Log4net

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, c#, logs

I am using **log4net** for creating execution logs of test cases which are created and being executed using Selenium Webdriver in C#. I was able to implement the logging functionality but I am facing an issue with the same or you can say I have a query related to this logging feature. I have seen that every web link which provides information about this logging has shown it in a way like:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
logger.Info("Browser is launched");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(BaseURL+"");
logger.Info("Navigate to the URL provided by the user");
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
logger.Info("Maximize the window");
```

i.e. I have to use this line `'logger.Info'` at all such places where logging is required.

Is there any way in which I can avoid using it repetitively? i.e. I use `'logger.Info'` only at one places and it creates logs for the whole test case execution automatically, means I want to avoid repeating this line again and again.

Reference links (these links shows that I have repeat this code of line):-

1. [learn-automation.com](http://learn-automation.com/how-to-create-log-files-in-selenium/)
2. [toolsqa.com](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/log4j-logging/)
3. [softwaretestinghelp.com](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/log4j-tutorial-selenium-tutorial-26/)
4. [eyecatch.no](https://www.eyecatch.no/blog/logging-with-log4net-in-c/)

Comment: Check out this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126934/automatic-log-when-entering-and-exiting-functions-log4net)

Comment: Check my answer: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17342/logging-every-action-with-custom-debug-method-good-idea/17348#17348

Answer (score 0):

Write some wrapper class with all the WebDrive Methods (add log messages there) and use those methods in your tests.

Example

```
public class WebDriverMethods {

  public static final LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(WebDriverMethods.class.getName());
  public void click(By by) {
     //click logic
     LOGGER.info(by+"Clicked");
  }

  public void type(By by,String data) {
     //sendKeys logic
     LOGGER.info(data+" data entered in "+by);
  }

   // write all the required methods


}
```

Use above methods in your testcase to get logs for each step performed.